# Convert string markups to HTML element through jQuery

Tags: jquery

Initial HTML output that I get from wordpress:

```
<div class="testimonial-name">Syed Haroon {{ Web Developer_ India }}</div>
```

Below given jQuery code will convert `{{` to `<span>` and `}}` to `</span>` and `_` to `,`

```
jQuery('.testimonial-name').text(function(index,text){
      return text.replace("{{",'<span>')
                 .replace("}}",'</span>')
                 .replace('_',',');
    })
```

After running the above code the result is:

```
<div class="testimonial-name">Syed Haroon &lt;span&gt; Web Developer, India &lt;/span&gt;</div>
```

What I actually need is:

```
<div class="testimonial-name">Syed Haroon <span>Web Developer, India</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of text

```js
jQuery('.testimonial-name').html(function(index, html) {
  return html.replace("{{", '<span>')
    .replace("}}", '</span>')
    .replace('_', ',');
})
```

```css
span{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial-name">Syed Haroon {{ Web Developer_ India }}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.html()` instead `.text()`:

```
jQuery('.testimonial-name').html(function(index,html){
    return html.replace("{{",'<span>')
        .replace("}}",'</span>')
        .replace('_',',');
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zfzopjyw/)